# pip: Uninstalling package from specific directory

Tags: python, pip, uninstallation

I installed package into specific local directory using `pip install -t <dir>`.

Now I want to uninstall it, but I cannot find a way to uninstall **from** that specific directory. For `uninstall` there is no valid option *-t | --target*, which exists for `install` command.

Comment: if you run `pip list` can you see the package?

Comment: No, `pip list` shows me the global package list

Comment: I think you could simply delete that folder if it contains only that package or delete the package inside it if are more other packages in the folder.

Comment: That folder is the top level folder of all packages I installed for specific project. I cannot delete it. I just need to delete single package with all its dependencies. Some kind of "undo" of `pip install -t <dir>`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Remove them manually.   `pip` does not keep hidden directories of installed packages and scans directories such as `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` directly to determine what is installed.

So, if you installed something using `-t` just go to the directory you specified and delete all traces, including any metadata files.  For example,

```
$ mkdir localpips
$ pip install -t localpips docopt
Downloading/unpacking docopt
  Downloading docopt-0.6.2.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_garyw/docopt/setup.py) egg_info for package docopt

Installing collected packages: docopt
  Running setup.py install for docopt

Successfully installed docopt
Cleaning up...
$ cd localpips
$ ls -l
total 48
drwxr-xr-x 2 garyw garyw  4096 Jul  6 17:27 docopt-0.6.2.egg-info
-rw-r--r-- 1 garyw garyw 19946 Jul  6 17:27 docopt.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 garyw garyw 23326 Jul  6 17:27 docopt.pyc
$
```

To uninstall it, just go into `localpips` and delete the files and directories that were created.

I know, it's not that elegant, and sometimes you have no idea what may be related to what if you didn't observe the install carefully, but that's the way it is.

Comment: You are right that it's not hidden. My problem is about package dependencies. I have multiple packages installed. Each one installed also its dependencies. Now I need to remove one of them with its dependencies (but only in case they are not in use by other packages). It's not a trivial task. I was sure there should be an opposite of `pip install -t <...>`

Comment: Sadly, pip does not have a robust dependency tracker, so removing a package (even in the system directory) does not remove its dependencies.  There is a standard way packages declare their requirements, but since there is no database kept of what requires what at any given time, there is no uninstall "with dependencies' option regardless of whether you use `-t` or not.  There is a package on github called pip-autoremove that does analysis and removal, but it doesn't support custom directories.  :-(